# How do I add empty value to a variable between 5 AM to 10 AM in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

what's wrong with this code? I want to add empty value when the timing is between 5 AM to 10 AM.
I tried below code but not working.

```
if(date('H')=='05' && date('H')<'10')
{
    $san="";
    
}
```

Comment: Don't compare the time to a string...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you mean `>=` ? the first condition has `==` in your code

```
if(date('H') >= 5 && date('H') < 10)
{
    $san="";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
$currentDateHour = date('G');

if(in_array($currentDateHour, range(5,10)))
{
    $san="";
}
```

This following `if` statment will true between `05:00:00` and `10:59:59`